# DELL Inspiron N 5050 doesn't Power On until I Plug-in the Charger

Tags: power-supply, dell-inspiron, charger

I bought a `Dell Inspiron N 5050` last week, and recently discovered a problem with my laptop. It doesn't Power On until and unless I Plug-in the charger.

After I plug-in the charger, it boots up fine, and continues to work well after disconnecting the charger.

I don't know what the problem is exactly? I was planning to contact Customer Care, but I wanted to know if I could fix it myself. Please help!

Comment: It seems like problem in battery or connection between battery and board.

Comment: If I were you and I bought it as NEW laptop, I will send it straight back to Dell, and get a refund. Then I buy a different laptop with the same price OR maybe the same one again. Because I paid for a new laptop, so I'm expecting a FULLY WORKING one with no issues. If I send it back to them to fix, they might just open it (unscrew) and fix it, which would be useless and the laptop would be not NEW anymore, so why did I pay the price of a new laptop in the first place?

Comment: @hannanessay Hi... do you remember if they checked the battery with another computer? BTW take in consideration to accept one answer, maybe your own too, so that the system will not bump the question up...

Answer (score 0):

Pull out the battery and hold down the charge test LED until it turns off. If it lights up again a second later, the number of lights indicates the type of baterry error. At least that's how the Latitudes work.

Also check and see if there are any error messages in the BIOS power page about either the AC adapter or the battery. If there are no BIOS errors, it's likely that the systemboard is bad.

If you could test the battery in a known good system, that would be definative. From the description it looks like a 90% chance that it's the systemboard. You may be able to update the BIOS to fix it.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, I'll get back to you once i try this.

Comment: I tried your suggestion. It didn't work. The Charging LED light doesn't glow at all.

Comment: I also tried updating the BIOS, it said the existing one was the latest.

Comment: assuming the light is on on the ac adapter before you plug it in to the pc its the systemboard.  if you plug the acadapter in to the pc and the light goes out on the ac adapter bad systemboard. it is possible that it could be the battery. We have enough pc's around at work that we just use a known good to test so I never worried about testing a battery much. if its in warranty call dell and have them repair it for you.  if you put your service tag in to the support.dell.com site it will tell you remaining warranty.

Answer (score 0):

I had contacted the customer care and an agent came over. He replaced the system board but still the problem remained. Later he mentioned that it might be a power button issue.  But anyway he suggested me to claim for a new system. I have done so.

Comment: Err, the problem is probably your battery. Did he check the battery?

Comment: Yes the battery was perfectly fine. It passed all the tests.

Comment: You pressed the charge button but it didn't light up at all? Each light is supposed to represent ~20% of the battery charge. If none lit up, it isn't holding a charge.

Answer (score 0):

#### This is a late answer usable in similar cases.

You state a problem related with battery/computer interaction <sup>[[1](https://superuser.com/a/1099107/257269)]</sup>.
As usual when you cannot be sure about where is the problem, you have to separate all the possible causes and check for them, one by one.

- You plug-in the charger. The computer starts. You unplug it, it continue to work (for the normal period in which it should). This **exclude** that the problem is that the **battery didn't charge**. But it doesn't exclude that the electronic of the battery is communicating a wrong state to the computer.
- You (your Customer Care Center) may try to **use the battery with another computer**.
  If all works fine you can **exclude** that is the battery **electronic too**.
- You can use a **different battery on your computer**. If all works fine you can exclude that is the electronic of the computer.

Since the computer starts and continue to work as you described, you may want to **try recalibrate the battery gauge** <sup>[[2](http://www.howtogeek.com/172271/how-to-calibrate-your-laptops-battery-for-accurate-battery-life-estimates/)]</sup>, there are different methods and tools, search for one suitable for your laptop.

---

#### Reasons

Why can this happen? Because when you add a load (someone that asks for energy) to a battery its voltage decreases. If it decreases below a limit your battery can *communicate* to be discharged and the computer will not start at all. The limit can be not correctly set or a malfunction can be present.

When you plug the charger, the voltage will be the higher between the battery one and the charger one (that usually is higher that the first one). This can be enough for the computer/battery to interpret it as a fully charged battery and to start.

You may [**read more**](https://superuser.com/a/1099107/257269) about interaction *battery/computer* on this other answer.

---

> [image: battery plot]
> <sub>Image from a blog <sup>[[3](http://www.disk91.com/2014/technology/hardware/start-playing-with-lipo-batteries/)]</sup>. In red the line below the one the battery can say (the system can assume) that it is fully discharged (and stops to work or not start at all). The age, or the defects, can deviate the behaviour of the battery from the expected one; a malfunction too.</sub>